# PHP not sending form to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I've been able to connect to my database. manual insert data to a table by using my own inputs with the `VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$userPassword')";` code but for some reason when I try to pass the above variables to my database it will input blank data into my table. this is my PHP for my `welcome.php` page:

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "@Password";
  $dbname = "accounts";

  // Create connection
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }



  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Ausername']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
  $userPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Apassword']);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password)
  VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$userPassword')";

  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
  } else {
     echo "Error: " . $sql . mysqli_error($conn);
  }

  mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

note that on the welcome page the below code will pass the info from my form and display it appropriately but will not add it to my database:

```
<html>
<body>
    Welcome <?php echo $_POST["Ausername"]; ?><br>
    Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?><br>
    password is <?php echo $_POST["Apassword"]; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

my form code:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="welcome.php" method="post">

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Ausername" placeholder="Username" name="Ausername" required>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Apassword" placeholder="Password" name="Apassword" required>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <br>                
                        <br>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="button" name="submit" value="submit">
                            <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>
                            Sign Up
                        </button>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Change **$link** to **$conn** in the escape calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$link` has not been defined in your code, your are using `$conn` to create your connection to the database, so you need to change

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Ausername']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
$userPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Apassword']);
```

to

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Ausername']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$userPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Apassword']);
```